# How to convert a C# object initializer to use a constructor using Resharper structural find and replace

Tags: c#, resharper, structural-search

I want to use a Resharper structural search and replace template to automatically replace examples of this:

`new Fruit { Name = "Apple", IsTasty = true }`

With this:

`new Fruit("Apple", true)`

(Note, the required constructor already exists)

I've tried various combinations like this:

`new $type$ { Name = $name$, IsTasty = $isTasty$ };`

...using various different Placeholder types, but R# doesn't find any of the examples in my code. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: what Placeholder types did you try?

Comment: I tried Identifier, Expression and Argument. I also tried making the assignment targets (Name / IsTasty) into placeholders too... no success

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I just did this in resharper (9.0.2 I think)

Create pattern: FruityChange

- new $type$ { Name = $param1$, IsTasty = $param2$ }
- $type$ is a type
- $param1$ is an expression of type string
- $param2$ is an expression of type bool
- Pattern Severity "Show as error"

with class Fruit

```
public class Fruit
{
    public Fruit(string name, bool isTasty)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsTasty = isTasty;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsTasty { get; set; }
}
```

And that underlined the expression in the code editor and alt-tab gave me the "Replace With" option for it.  It at least works on my machine :-)

Comment: This worked - thanks! 

I think the issue was that I had included the terminating semi-colon at the end of the statement. You must leave this off.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it seems R# treats your placeholders as identifiers, and the pattern match fails.

Double-click each placeholder on the right side, and change "identifier" to "expression".

[image]

Comment: you could also replace 'Name' and 'IsTasty' with `Identifier`s if need be