# Can I use re-sharper to extract a constructor method from an object initializer

Tags: constructor, refactoring, resharper

For example I have this code

```
var person = new HighrisePerson()
{
    FirstName = firstName,
    ContactData = new HighriseContactData()
    {
        EmailAddresses = new List<HighriseEmailAddress>
        {
            new HighriseEmailAddress
            {
                Address = email,
                Location = "Work"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I'd like to refactor to this:

```
var person = new HighrisePerson(firstName, email)
```

and I'd like this constructor added to my HighrisePerson Class

```
public HighrisePerson(string firstName, string email)
{
    FirstName = firstName,
    ContactData = new HighriseContactData()
    {
        EmailAddresses = new List<HighriseEmailAddress>
        {
            new HighriseEmailAddress
            {
                Address = email,
                Location = "Work"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678162/how-to-convert-a-c-sharp-object-initializer-to-use-a-constructor-using-resharper comes close : using R# structural search/replace